# google caja how to use

Tags: javascript, portlet, opensocial, google-caja

let say i have a page , and i want to allow 3rd party to embed small application/iframe into my page. in order to use caja on my page to secure the 3rd party small app/iframe. do i need to put any extra javascript/serverside code in order to use caja?  fetching of the 3rd party small application is done through proxy or direct iframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to host a Caja module in your page? Check out [the integration guide documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CajaHostingModules).

Answer (score 5):

There are two main ways to use the Caja rewriter; if your server is coded in Java, then you can build Caja into your server and invoke the classes directly.  Otherwise, you run Caja as its own server (the Cajoling Service) and it will rewrite the third-party code.  That code needs to be served on a page with the Caja runtime library and some setup code that grants the cajoled code some portion of the DOM to render in.  Like the first poster said, the CajaHostingModules page is an example of one way to do this.

Please follow up with any further questions on the mailing list: [google-caja-discuss@googlegroups.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-caja-discuss).  Thanks!